# Jquery AJAX call not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, post

I'm trying to build a sign-up page. I've hosted what I have so far here: http://www.wikinewscheck.com/sign_up.html

I'm using bootstrapValidator which seems to work well. When it has finished the validating after a button click I want it to disable the submit button and post the form as shown in the code below:
Now I'm terrible at Javascripts so it's probably a basic error, however, from stepping through the code, it seems to completely skip past the code to disable the button, and ajax post.

Why is this?

All code available at link above, or can post more if required.

Thanks

```
  $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
      //validation part seems to work well so deleted code. Can be viewed through link above if required.
  })

 .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {

      // script seems to completley skip this section
      $this = $("#registerButton");
      $this.prop("disabled", true); // Disable submit button until AJAX call is complete to prevent duplicate messages
      $.ajax({
        url: "././php/register.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          first_name: first_name,
          last_name: last_name,
          email: email,
          user_name: user_name,
          email: email,
          user_password: user_password,
          confirm_password: confirm_password
        },
        cache: false,
```

Comment: is it because your code is running in script mode and you didn't declare your var? Try `var $this = `

Comment: put a console.log at the beginning of the function just to check it's even running at all

Comment: Part of the problem could be with the line you define your URL on in the ajax call. url: "././php/register.php", "./" refers to the current directory, and you're trying find /php/register.php in the current folder your ajax script is in. In plain English this line is basically saying "look in the current folder, and then look in the current folder for the directory called php and then the file register.php". Any time you have two dots and a slash, or "../" that will tell it to look one level up from the current directory and might be (at least one thing) that needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some conflict in your references to scripts...

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- External CSS (some can be deleted)-->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="js/sign_up.js"></script>
```

Remove all you references and put those what I provided inside head-tag. Then when you confirm that you get inside "success.form.bv" event, you can bring in some of your custom scripts, if needed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This worked, as you suggested, but I don't understand why it worked? I always avoided butting scripts in the head as I thought this was best practice. Would you mind explaining what the conflicts you mentioed where? Many thanks

Comment: You had jquery and bootstrapValidation reference in header and after footer. I did not checked does it version conflict or something else, but you had duplicated references and that give you a conflict somewhere.